# Partitioning a set of numbers.

Tags: combinatorics

Consider a list of numbers which can have values from $1$ to $10$, and two groups that can fit a maximum of $100$ value. Now, the numbers have to be split between these two groups such that no group has over $100$ value. What is the maximum total value of the numbers, such that it is always possible to split into groups without going over 100?

I know that the maximum value possible is 200, and I have started to eliminate cases by choosing awkward divisions: such as 22*9 + 2, which will not fit for 200.

But I do not know what the true maximum value is.

Comment: Please share what you have done.

Comment: I have now done that.

Comment: What is preventing the list to have two hundred $1$s, or twenty $10$s?

Comment: The list isn't split by me, it contains all possible values. So some values can't be split properly like 200, I gave example.

Comment: "...and two groups that can fit a maximum of 100 value" : what does this signify?

Comment: you are not allowed to get a sum of values over 100 in a group.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if the smallest element is $k$ and the total is at most $201 - k$ then we can ignore this element, partition the rest, and then add it to the group with the smaller total, which will necesarily be at most $100 - k$. So every total up to $191$ works and so does $192$ since for that to be the total not all the numbers can be $10$.

Using these restrictions, searching all the possibilities for $193$ onwards is easy enough by [computer search](https://pastebin.com/KBALQKVE). According to the output, everything up to $196$ can be split, and there are $4$ lists of total $197$ that cannot:

- $32 \times 6 + 5$
- $24 \times 8 + 5$
- $23 \times 8 + 7 + 6$
- $22 \times 8 + 3 \times 7$

The first paragraph suggests two greedy algorithms for finding a partition: consider the numbers largest to smallest, and put them in whichever half currently has (1) the lower total (2) the higher total if it fits. The smallest total (1) fails for is $4 \times 10 + 17 \times 9 = 193$ (with the valid splittings $4 \times 10 + 6 \times 9$, $11 \times 9$ and $3 \times 10 + 7 \times 9$, $10 + 10 \times 9$). Similarly the smallest total (2) fails for is $3 \times 10 + 12 \times 9 + 7 \times 8 = 194$ (with valid splittings $1 \times 10 + 10 \times 9$, $2 \times 10 + 2 \times 9 + 7 \times 8$ etc).

Comment: Each of the four examples is easy to verify by hand. Eg whichever half has a $5$ can have at most $\lfloor 95/6 \rfloor = 15$ $6$s but $17 \times 6 > 100$.